# Is there a way to get the width and height of powerpoint slide without active document?

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

I'm writing some code for automatically publishing PowerPoint slides.

I'v already found that `ActiveDocument` in PowerPoint application object allow me to know width and height of slides.

However, When I start the application with `MsoTriStat.msoFalse` flag, PowerPoint doesn't appear to me of course and I can't figure out width and height of slide because `Application` doesn't have any `ActiveWindow`.

So, is there another way to get width and height of slide?

**UPDATE**
Here is my test code

```
Application app = new Application();
Presentation presentation = app.Presentations.Add(MsoTriState.msoFalse);
Slide slide = presentation.Slides.Add(1, PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutTitleOnly);

Console.WriteLine("Shapes in slide: {0}", slide.Shapes.Count);
Console.WriteLine("slide name: {0}", slide.Name);

Console.WriteLine(app.ActivePresentation.Name);

app.ActiveWindow.Width = 1024;
app.ActiveWindow.Width = 768;
app.ActiveWindow.View.Zoom = 100;

presentation.SaveAs(@"C:\Temp\ppt1.pptx");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `presentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight` and `presentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth`

Answer (score 0):

When you open a presentation it becomes the active presentation.  The ActivePresentation object will give you access to the properties you need.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @Steve. When I write test code according to your advice, however, it says that there is no active presentation. I guess that there is no Active things when I add new presentation with `MsoTriState.msoFalse` flag. I updated a question with my test code.

Comment: Try adding a new presentation then setting your Presentation variable to app.Presentations(1)  (Sorry for the vagueness; I'm not a C# programmer; basically, work with the first element of the Presentations collection)